# Boost Depth First Visit with avoidance and early exit

Tags: c++, depth-first-search, boost-graph

Consider the following (directed) tree

```
    0
    |
    1
   /|\
  / | \
 2' 3' 4'
 |  |
 5' 6'
```

where all edges are directed downward.

The goal is to traverse this tree starting at 0 in a depth-first manner and return the first vertex with a *pebble* (indicated by an apostrophe ') and terminate the traversal. Furthermore, I would also like to avoid a given vertex.

For example, I want to find a pebble by avoiding the vertex 2. In that case the order of visiting is: 0 to 1, 1 to 2 (avoid, return to 1); 1 to 3 (pebble found, end). There should be no attempt to discover 5, 6, and 4.

I have implemented this with boost BGL via depth_first_visit. I can get the correct output to display on the console, for example:

```
Discover vertex  0
Discover vertex  1

Discover vertex  2
Avoiding vertex  2
Finished vertex  2

Discover vertex  3
Found a pebble on vertex 3 and stopping dfs.
```

However, the issue is that the depth_first_visit doesn't really stop at vertex 3. While I can make it not examine the edges 25 and 36 (and hence not discover 5 and 6) via a terminator function, the edge 14 will be examined (because examine_edge was invoked an all outgoing edges of 1 as soon as 1 was discovered) and therefore 4 will be discovered.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct pebbles{
    int num_pebbles = 1;
};

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,pebbles>;

struct Visitor : boost::default_dfs_visitor
{       
    using Vertex = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor;
    using Edge = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor;

    boost::optional<Vertex> avoid;
        
    void discover_vertex(Vertex s, Graph const &g){
        if (stop_dfs) return;
        std::cerr << "Discover vertex:   " << s << std::endl;
        
        if (s==avoid) {std::cerr << "Avoiding vertex:   " << s << std::endl; return; }
        
        if (g[s].num_pebbles != 0 ){
            stop_dfs = true;
            std::cerr << "Found a pebble on vertex: " << s << " and stopping dfs." << std::endl;
            return;
            }
    }

    //void examine_edge(Edge e, Graph const& ) const { std::cerr << "Examining edge:  " << e << std::endl; }
    
    void finish_vertex(Vertex s, Graph const&) const {
        if (stop_dfs) return;
        std::cerr << "Finished vertex:   " << s << std::endl;           
    }

    //terminator function
    bool operator()(Vertex s, Graph const& g) const {
        return ((s == avoid) || (g[s].num_pebbles != 0));
    };

   private:
    bool stop_dfs = false;
};


int main(){
        
    Graph g;

    //test graph g = {{0,1,2,3,4,5,6},{01,12,13,14,25,36}}
    boost::add_edge(0,1,g);
    boost::add_edge(1,2,g);
    boost::add_edge(1,3,g);
    boost::add_edge(1,4,g);
    boost::add_edge(2,5,g);
    boost::add_edge(3,6,g);

    g[0].num_pebbles = 0;
    g[1].num_pebbles = 0;    
    
    Visitor peb_vis_termfunc;
    std::vector<boost::default_color_type> colormap(num_vertices(g));

    peb_vis_termfunc.avoid = 2; //avoid vertex 2

    boost::depth_first_visit(g,0,peb_vis_termfunc,colormap.data(),peb_vis_termfunc);
    
    return 0;
}
```

It's easy to verify that the edge (1,4) is indeed examined by uncommenting the examine_edge function. I would like to not have to examine (1,4) at all and completely exit depth_first_visitor once a pebble is found.

I have read in the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/graph/doc/faq.html) that the intended way to force an early exit is to throw an exception, however I don't understand how to do that in this case (I'm a relative novice with C++ and STL/Boost).

I would also greatly appreciate any comments on style, good practice or improvements of the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can just throw an exception like this:

```
if (g[s].num_pebbles != 0 ) {
    std::cerr << "Found a pebble on vertex: " << s << " and stopping dfs." << std::endl;
    throw std::exception();
}
```

and then:

```
try {
    boost::depth_first_visit(g,0,peb_vis_termfunc,colormap.data(),peb_vis_termfunc);
}
catch (std::exception) {
    std::cout <<  "finished searching." << std::endl;
}
```

And I don't have any suggestions about style, code looks reasonable, however, I did notice that the compile time was large for such a small example (as is usually the case with Boost library), and unless you are planning to add a lot more functionality within the same context, my only suggestion would be to write it yourself since it will be much leaner.

Comment: That worked, thanks. This is just a toy example, so that I can understand how BGL works. Other libraries that I'm using (e.g. CGAL) use BGL, so I want to be consistent with that. I'm not working with very large graphs, so hopefully compile time will not become an issue.

Comment: No problem. I have been working recently with boost::python, and yeah big ugly error messages, large binaries and long compile times I think it's because of all the templating and the documentation is sometimes wrong since each version has slightly different syntax changes. I'm not trying to put you off it, but just some things to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

On the topic of style, I love your code. It has many subtle choices that lead to good, readable code. Cleverly combining the visitor and termination function works well due the well-timed comment.

Most notable feedback I would have is that you include the wrong header for `depth_first_visit` :)

Personally, I favour brief code. So, I'd leverage ADL a bit more and avoid going through the graph traits unless you need to support user-defined/adapted graphs. Note that there's a null vertex for most graph types. Here's a simplified version that also limits the scope of the visitor.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d0a9cc34dd6e265)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    int num_pebbles = 1;
};
using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Node>;

int main() {
    Graph g;

    add_edge(0, 1, g);
    add_edge(1, 2, g);
    add_edge(1, 3, g);
    add_edge(1, 4, g);
    add_edge(2, 5, g);
    add_edge(3, 6, g);

    g[0].num_pebbles = 0;
    g[1].num_pebbles = 0;

    struct Visitor : boost::default_dfs_visitor {
        using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
        struct Hit { Vertex v; };

        Vertex avoid = Graph::null_vertex();

        void discover_vertex(Vertex v, Graph const& g) const {
            std::cerr << "Visit vertex:   " << v << std::endl;

            if (v == avoid)
                std::cerr << "Avoided vertex: " << v << std::endl;
            else if (g[v].num_pebbles)
                throw Hit{v};
        }
    };

    try {
        std::vector<boost::default_color_type> colormap(num_vertices(g));

        depth_first_visit(g, 0, Visitor{.avoid = 2}, colormap.data());
    } catch (Visitor::Hit hit) {
        std::cerr << "Hit a pebble on vertex: " << hit.v << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Printing

```
Visit vertex:   0
Visit vertex:   1
Visit vertex:   2
Avoided vertex: 2
Visit vertex:   5
Hit a pebble on vertex: 5
```

Comment: I just realized that the original code had an issue: the visitor is passed-by-value so you should have made the mutable state (`stop_dfs`) by-reference, see [docs: _"The visitor object is passed by value"_](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/graph/doc/depth_first_search.html#:~:text=The%20visitor%20object%20is%20passed%20by%20value) and the corresponding footnote.

Comment: (1/2) The `stop_dfs` is now redundant, but I understand what you are saying. I somehow missed `null_vertex()` in the documentation, thanks. In your solution 5 is visited, but it shouldn't be, because 2 is avoided. I realize I wasn't clear and concise enough in explaining what I mean by avoiding a vertex `v`: the outcome of the traversal should be a path from the source to a pebble that doesn't pass through `v`.

Comment: (2/2) This I can easily fix by adding the terminator function back in, however I have to first instantiate it as `Visitor termfunc`, I can't just pass `Visitor` into depth_first_visit like you have. For example, I'm calling it like this: `depth_first_visit(g,0,Visitor{.avoid=2},colormap.data(),termfunc);`. This works but somehow doesn't feel like I should be doing it like that - is there any way to do this without instantiating termfunc?

Comment: @RandyMarsh I see. Ignoring the "avoid semantics" for now: I didn't imagine the termination function being evaluated earlier. If so, you might do [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a8f3d9dd85c08ef) to at least share the avoid state, or, of course, [don't use a visitor at all](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f277858cb62827a7)! This leads to an even cleaner version without exceptions: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69ce3abc4a474ab2

Comment: Now let's address the elephant in the room: _"explaining what I mean by avoiding a vertex v: the outcome of the traversal should be a path from the source to a pebble that doesn't pass through v"_ --> this squarely implies that the DFS cannot work, as you don't avoid the paths while continuing the search. What you really seem to need is a filtered search. Let me draft one up...

Comment: Here's the concept of filtering the graph: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a83a01e255ecb83 If you only want the first path to a pebble, back to throwing: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75752504fde97d0e. I have a latent hunch you might be able to use `make_dfs_visitor` to hit the sweet spot (declaring the visitor using a lambda) but I don't think I have time to look into it. You can [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+make_dfs_visitor) if you want

Comment: what do you mean by "you don't avoid the paths while continuing the search"? The terminator function will tell `depth_first_visit` to ignore all the out-edges of the vertex `v` that is to be avoided, so it will ignore all sub-paths starting at `v`. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I should have checked the docs. Terminator function doesn't sound like a "pruning function". It sounds like "termination". Apparently they meant it to "terminate" the current branch only. That makes it more applicable indeed